# Почему выборка работает некорректно?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Почему такая выборка работает не корректно?

```
$("body:not(.modal-content)").css({
        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(4px)'
    });
```

Оно применяется для всего без исключения. Версия jquery 1.1.
Я делаю размытость всей страницы, за исключением модального окна от bootstrap.

Comment: @Fikret, потому что выбирается элемент body?

Comment: Ну да, все body, кроме div.modal-content.

Comment: @Fikret, нет, выбирается **только** body, не имеющий класса `modal-content`